# How to return javascript content without enclosing script tags from view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to localize client side Javascript in a ASP .NET MVC application.  The way I've settled on this is I want to return a JavaScript object from a view page.

The idea is very similar to what is described here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robj/archive/2009/03/12/localized-javascript-resources-with-mvc.aspx

It's unclear to me from the blog post what the view (or partial view?) looks like. I would like to do something like this:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
ForumsRes = 
{
    prompt_clearAbuseReason: <%=       AntiXss.JavaScriptEncode(Resource.prompt_clearAbuseReason) %>,    
    prompt_deleteReason: <%= AntiXss.JavaScriptEncode(Resource.prompt_deleteReason) %>,     
    prompt_pageExit: <%= AntiXss.JavaScriptEncode(Resource.prompt_pageExit) %>,    
    prompt_reportAbuseReason: <%= AntiXss.JavaScriptEncode(Resource.prompt_reportAbuseReason) %>,    
    prompt_stickyUntil: <%= AntiXss.JavaScriptEncode(Resource.prompt_stickyUntil) %>,    
    prompt_undeleteReason: <%= AntiXss.JavaScriptEncode(Resource.prompt_undeleteReason) %>,       
    rte_alreadyOpen: <%= AntiXss.JavaScriptEncode(Resource.rte_alreadyOpen) %>}
</script>
```

within the view definition.  By having the script tag actually in the .cshtml file, I can make an external reference to the .cshtml file and I will get intellisense (as per http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/21/vs-2008-javascript-intellisense.aspx).

However, I want to reference the javascript (really .cshtml file) something like this from another view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/res/MyResources")"></script>
```

where the res/MyResources URL would be mapped (via the custom route) to the controller that invokes the view (or partial view) that serves up the JavaScript.  The problem is, I think, that what I return in the view includes the  tags.  I want this at design time, so I can get the intellisense.  But when the javascript is return at run time, I want to return the content of the view (or partial view) with the script tags scripted.

As you can probably tell, I'm pretty green at ASP .NET MVC, so hopefully what I said make some sense.  Is there a way to strip the  tags within the controller?  I imagine I could do something on the client side (maybe using JQuery), but I'd rather have what is served up be a vanilla javascript external file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer I was looking for on the MSDN ASP .NET forum.  Here's the answer:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1765704/4819373.aspx/1?p=True&t=634641505060799388

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you need to set the `Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";`

I'm not sure how you can have intellisense and not have the script tags output.  You may be able to do something like:

```
@if(false) {
     <script>
}

javascript code here

@if(false) {
     </script>
}
```

**EDIT**: Just a note on security, script files accessed this way can be pulled cross domain in the browser and are vulnerable to attack, so you should avoid anything sensitive.

Comment: Thank you Paul!  The tip about the ContentType will prove useful, I'm sure.  So far, my controller looks like this:

Comment: ATSYMBOL{
           Layout = null;
     }
 
     ATSYMBOLlif (false){
         <script type ="text/javascript">
      }
         var externalFunc = function (parameter) {
            alert("parameter:" + parameter);
        };
      ATSYMBOLif (false)
    {
        </script>
    }

Comment: I actually get errors at design time (expecting a closing } at the top of the file).  At runtime, the script does not get loaded...Sorry about the formatting of these comments; I don't know how to enter code blocks nor line breaks :(